# Props from getstaticprops flash up on page load before altered client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, use-effect

I'm developing a simple website using nextjs that displays events to users sorted by date. I use ISR and getstaticprops to hydrate the site with events but since i have no way to tell the users timezone before hand the events are filtered using the users timezone client side.

When i first load the page you can see the static events for a split second before the events are filtered client side.

I know i could use state and useEffect to avoid this with something like:

```
const [hasFiltered, setHasFiltered] = useState(false)

if (!hasFiltered) {

return <></>
}
```

But my problem is i need the events in the src for SEO reasons. If i use the above i don't see the events/ dont think googlebots see the events as it waits for them to be filtered which is client side.

Im guessing i could do some workaround like make the text transparent until events are filtered but i think thats against googles rules etc.

Is there a workaround for this using next js/ react?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to use the user's IP server-side to determine the timezone before serving the initial page.

Comment: @ChrisG If the props are only generated say every 100seconds with ISR how would that work? Would that not mean i'd have to change to server side rendering? I'm wanting to keep it mainly static for performance and costs.

Comment: You obviously cannot use ISR in the context of data that depends on the user's timezone.

Comment: @ChrisG The way i have it working is it provides events within a frame of 24hr before the current server time and 24hr after so it can account for all timezones, then filters them client side for the user. It works pretty well except for the issue above. The events are regenerated daily and on demand for any updates with the new on demand isr

Comment: This would require SSR to properly setup the data with the right timezone on the server-side.